# How to implement infinite scroll, endless pagination using the zinnia blog app from Django

Tags: ajax, django, pagination, infinite-scroll, zinnia

This is my first question here

I want to implement an infinite scrolling (or endless pagination ) on a blog powered by the [zinnia](http://django-blog-zinnia.readthedocs.org/en/v0.13/)  app from Django.

My blog structure is the same as zinnia blog, i haven't coded anything different to it. I tried using "django endless pagination" because it's documentation says i can create a [twitter style pagination](https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html) but i couldn't resolve where to put it's snippets of code.

***I don't mind if it can be solved by using django endless pagination or not.***

My PIP FREEZE looks like this:

```
Django==1.5.1
Pillow==2.3.1
argparse==1.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
django-blog-zinnia==0.13
django-endless-pagination==2.0
django-filebrowser==3.5.6
django-grappelli==2.4.10
django-mptt==0.6.0
django-tagging==0.3.2
django-tinymce==1.5.2
django-xmlrpc==0.1.5
easy-thumbnails==1.3
feedparser==5.1.3
pyparsing==2.0.1
pytz==2014.2
raven==4.2.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I really appreciate your suggestions.

P.D: Let me know if you need anything else to give an appropriate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in the client side, by using this library : https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Works fine on http://fantomas.willbreak.it/ like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hfeed').infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '.paginator',
    nextSelector: '.paginator .next a',
    itemSelector: '.hentry',
    contentSelector: '.hfeed aside',
    bufferPx: 1000,
    maxPage: 5,
    loading: {
    msgText: '<p>Chargement des articles suivants...</p>',
    finishedMsg: '',
    img: '/static/img/loader.gif',
    },
    }, function (newElements) {
        $(newElements).find('pre').each(function (i, e) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(e)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Links are broke, please provide appropriate links.